# How can make my MainForm refresh?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a MainForm and some components on it (RichTextBox, button, 2 textBoxes).

When I click my button, my application writes some text in the richtextbox. After making some changes in the richtextBox and clicking again on the button, I still see the old text on the richtextbox.

How can I make my MainForm refresh and also clear richtextBox each time I click on the button?

I tried `MainForm.Refresh();` and `richtextBox.Clear();` but no luck!

Comment: Please provide source code otherwise no one will know what the problem is.

Comment: did you try to invoke invalidate();

Comment: I think [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) should be sufficient, try call richtextBox.Refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Use `richtextBox.RTF = String.Empty;`  to clear the text in richtext box.

And then set the `RTF` when you click the button.